# Does Android TV support multitouch?

Tags: android, android-tv

Does Android TV support multitouch? I've been asked to estimate the development of an android tv app but I couldnt answer this question and couldnt find anything about this on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Touch is not supported at all.

"In order to make your app successful on TV devices, you must design new layouts that can be easily understood from 10 feet away, and provide navigation that works with just a directional pad and a select button."

http://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/index.html